# How to provide guest user permissions to an application in powerbi service? (not in organization)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, user-permissions, power-bi-report-server

The scope of the project is to provide permissions to every single guest user that clicks on the [link](https://app.powerbi.com/Redirect?action=OpenApp&appId=674eacf5-740d-4076-8361-e28a96cd7f54&ctid=7bf9317d-6318-4aaf-9121-ebead9056682/) (link is from powerbi service). From what I've experienced this can only be done within the organization from the app perspective.

What is the best practice to provide guest users/everyone access to the powerbi application without having to approve users?

[image: I would think this image is the area to solve some of this, but not sure...]

I tried changing of the app permissions to everyone in the org, and turning on the setting allowing azure active Directory guest users to access Power BI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having access to Power BI doesn't grant them access to any workspaces or apps.  For that you need a security group, eg an [AAD Dynamic Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/use-dynamic-groups).

Comment: Thank you David. 

Created the Dynamic Group, then attached the group to my application. That should do the trick then?